# Wordpress remove "Auto Draft" from the home page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

At the main page of my website:

http://automatenspielex.com/

In the list of "kostenlos spiele", custom post type elements (posts alternatives) are showing "Auto Draft" link to a 404 page. There are no drafts or "Auto Draft" posts in Wordpress admin.

How do I remove this "Auto Draft"? Where does it come from?

Comment: Find your post id = 1206? It exist on your Posts?

Comment: There is no post with name "Auto Draft" and It's not possible to search by post ID

Comment: You can hover mouse in your title in Posts list you will see the post ID